# How can I handle this sloped laminate flooring transition?

Tags: flooring, laminate-floor, building, transition

We have recently converted our garage into a room and have a slope between the hallway and the new room (previously garage) because the new floor is higher due to insulation and screed depth. We opted for a slope as it seemed less of a trip hazard than a half\small step but now I am regretting it as the transition from hallway to garage in laminate may prove difficult.

I am going to lay Karndean korlock click and connect flooring in the new room but do not know what to use to transition into and out of the slope into the hallway. Is there transition strips on the market that can do this (e.g. that you can angle up or down)? Or should I revert and build the slope into a step...

[image: Floor]

Thanks

Comment: In your situation I would just use a pair of flush "transition" strips at the slope beginning and end.  If the grade change is very steep at the top, the transition may be slightly elevated; you'd want to kind of bend it down to match the floor surface, which you may be able to do with a little heat, and maybe a little moisture.

Comment: How long is the slope and what is the change in elevation?